# How to log echo statement with timestamp in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, logging, timestamp

I am currently using following to log stdout and stderr. I want to log echo statements along with timestamp.

```
exec 3>&1 1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
```

How can I achieve it using shell

Comment: Here is a comprehensive implementation of logging for bash: https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the exact intended behavior you may want the `ts`
utility.

```
% echo message | ts
Apr 16 10:56:39 message
```

You could also alias `echo`.

```
% sh
$ alias echo='echo $(date)'
$ echo message
Mon Apr 16 10:57:55 UTC 2018 message
```

Or make it a shell function.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo() {
    command echo $(date) "$@"
}

echo message
```

Comment: I want to store it in a file. How to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Here I'm using a function to simplify the line, but the main thing to look for is *process substitution*, that's the `>(log_it)` syntax.  `REPLY` is the default variable used by `read`.

```
logit() {
    while read
    do
        echo "$(date) $REPLY" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    done
}

LOG_FILE="./logfile"

exec 3>&1 1>> >(logit) 2>&1

echo "Hello world"
ls -l does_not_exist
```

The example puts into `logfile`:

```
Mon 16 Apr 2018 09:18:33 BST Hello world
Mon 16 Apr 2018 09:18:33 BST ls: does_not_exist: No such file or directory
```

You might wish to change the bare `$(date)` to use a better format.  If you are running bash 4.2 or later you can use `printf` instead, which will be more efficient, for example, instead of the `echo`:

```
# -1 means "current time"
printf "%(%Y-%m-%d %T)T %s\n" -1 "$REPLY"  >> ${LOG_FILE}
```

Gives:

```
2018-04-16 09:26:50 Hello world
2018-04-16 09:26:50 ls: does_not_exist: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant, thanks @cdarke! I'm now using something like the following so that I have more fine-grained control in the main part of my scripts - it logs everything I want and I still see stdout:

```
logouts() {
    while read
    do
        printf "%(%T)T %s\n" -1 "stdout: $REPLY"  | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
    done
}
logerrs() {
    while read
    do
        printf "%(%T)T %s\n" -1 "stderr: $REPLY"  >> ${LOG_FILE}
    done
}
LOG_FILE="./logfile"

main()
{
    echo "Hello world" 1>> >(logouts) 2>> >(logerrs)
    ls -l does_not_exist 1>> >(logouts) 2>> >(logerrs)
}
main "$@"
```

(Apologies to @cdarke: I couldn't format this into a comment - please upvote @cdarke answer if you find this useful.)